# Sign in to App Store

Tags: ios

After I've created an iCloud acc then sign in to App Store the status is shown that (your Apple ID was created for a different country. Go back and select that country, or choose a new Apple id. You must switch to the U.S store to create an id.

Noted : my country is Cambodia.

Answer (score 1):

If your are on an iPhone/iPad go on settings/ iTunes and App store, click on your email address and select disconnect.
Then connect again with your AppleID, that automatically gonna brink you to the correct store country (linked to your AppleID)